# How to set different fonts and sizes for different projects in IntelliJ-Idea

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-3.0

When I use a Mac and add an external monitor, the font displayed on the monitor is very confused. Is there any way to set different fonts for different projects?

Comment: different projects means different language projects ?

Comment: No, that means different widnows. As I "Open" or "Open Rencent", the prompt is in the new window or the current window.

Comment: What IJ version do you use? Please show the screenshots. What are the monitor configurations?

Comment: First of all, I'm sorry for my English is not very good~ and i mean the external display, and i use android-studio 3.1.2

Comment: IDE should adjust scaling for monitor, but it could be that you have monitors with different resolutions so the font look bigger on another monitor. Answering your question: there is no configuration to make the font per project. Try to restart IDE after you have plugged the monitor.

Comment: Fonts are configured on an application basis. You can't change or set  them on a project basis. And you can not set them to be different on different monitors. As Andrey points out, it should scale properly. But if not, and restarting IDEA does not solve it, you will have to find a compromise that works on both of your monitors. Or adjust your actual monitor settings so they are configured the same (or as close to the same as possible.)

Comment: ok, i see, and thanks to Javaru, Andrey and kvmahesh